# How to get date in 'dd/mon/yyyy' format from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to get date in `dd/mon/yyyy` format i.e `28/apr/2015`

```
select Birth_DATE 
from dbo.customer
```

where `Birth_DATE` is of `datetime` type. I have looked at all inbuilt `convert` types but nothing helped for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CONVERT` with style `106` and `REPLACE` the space like this.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),106),' ','/')
```

Your query would be

```
select REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),Birth_DATE,106),' ','/') from dbo.customer
```

Answer (score 0):

In General:

```
select cast(day(getdate()) as varchar(2))+'/'+ left(datename(mm,getdate()),3)+'/'+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4))
```

Your Code:

```
select cast(day(Birth_DATE) as varchar(2))+'/'+ left(datename(mm,Birth_DATE),3)+'/'+cast(year(Birth_DATE) as varchar(4)) from dbo.Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:
`CONVERT(data_type(length),expression,style)`

- data_type(length) : Specifies the target data type (with an optional length)
- expression : Specifies the value to be converted
- style :  Specifies the output format for the date/time

For your format:
`CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)`